# Selecting attribute values based on another attribute value with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to display an image using an xml file and SimpleXML

The XML code is

```
<icons>
  <icon size="tiny"    href="/FF02-tiny.jpg"    />
  <icon size="sidebar" href="/FF02-sidebar.jpg" />
  <icon size="full"    href="/FF02-full.jpg"    />
</icons>
```

I want to get the `href` attribute for the `size="full"` line.

I've tried

```
icons->icon->attributes()->href
```

but this just gives me the first `'tiny'` size. I know I should be using xpath but I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$icons->icon` will give you a `SimpleXMLElement` object that gives access to all `icon` child-elements of the `$icons` object.

From there you need to select which icon you want to get the attribute for. That works with [array](http://php.net/arrays#example-87)-like access and a numeric value for the zero-index child element and a string value for the attribute:

```
// specify what icon you want (third)
// and the attribute (href)
$icons->icon[2]['href'];
```

You find that documented in the PHP manual with the [SimpleXML basic examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) (*Example #3* and *Example #5*).

However this does not work if the position of the element you look for changes. So it's suggested that you use a [more specific xpath-expression instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14979814/367456).

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, if your XML varies ie 'full' isn't always the 3rd icon you'll need to try something different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can select the attribute node with an xpath expression:

```
list($iconHref) = $xml->xpath("//icon[@size='full']/@href");
echo $iconHref;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion... I tried this but it still gave me an array as the output. The answer by Boundless worked a treat...

Comment: @kaillum: I edited my answer so it would work. The way I suggest will work even if the structure of the XML changes.